# Unable to boot Ubuntu Properly

Tags: graphics, kubuntu

I have AMD Radeon 7470M 1GiB garphics card. I installed Ubuntu in the nomodeset, after my first boot, I just opened it from boot screen by pressing 'e' and replaced “quiet splash” with "nomodeset". It worked fine; I can log in but after that I installed AMD catalyst drivers for my graphics card. They are not working and even I opened the rc.local file as the root user 'sudo nano /etc/rc.local' copied and pasted the following lines just before the line exit 0 :

```
1) chown -R $USER:$USER /sys/kernel/debug
2) echo OFF > /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch
```

it doesn't work for me. Every time which I boot to OS I need to replace "quite splash" with "nomodeset" by pressing 'e' in the boot screen; only then can I log in to Ubuntu.

How can I fix this? It's very difficult to replace that thing every time.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[How to permanently set kernel boot option *nomodeset* on an installed OS (not wubi)](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1613132)**

1. Open a terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and enter:

`gksudo gedit /etc/default/grub`

Or if that does not work (as mentioned in the comments)

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

1. Enter your password when prompted, and the file `grub' will open in
   gedit.
2. Look for the line:

   `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"`

Change it to:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset"
```

Save the file and exit.

At the command prompt enter:

```
sudo update-grub
```

This will update Grub's config with the new settings permanently.

Comment: Thanks for your response, But Unable to open the file grub it showing error: (gksudo:2588): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

Comment: Try `sudo gedit /etc/default/grub`. I don't know why gksudo is not working.